# Rebase a branch from master if master has a revert of this branch

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to doing a `rebase` over master from a secondary branch but when I do that I lose the code because master have a revert for this same branch, how can I do the `rebase` and preserve the code.

Branches to rebase:

1. Master
2. Alerts

Comment: Please try to fix spelling and grammar to make this more readable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `git rebase -f`, which is designed to do exactly this. So in your case, you would check out your branch and then run `git rebase -f master`.

If you have an older Git, it's also possible to do this with by finding the last commit on `master` before your branch starts (call it `BASE`) and then doing `git rebase --onto master BASE`).